# Glitched Morticulturist Achievement help?

Tags: achievements, ios, plants-vs-zombies

I have **all** of Crazy Dave's plants. I have beaten Adventure mode countless times, unlocked everything (except Lucky Spin and the Zen Garden achievement. but I'm close!) and I have more money than I know what to do with.

When I bought the Imitator, I thought I was going to be set. But the Morticulturist achievement is still not there. This is the iPod Touch version.

Comment: This sort of thing happens a lot to Angry Birds players as well.  I think it's a glitch with Apple's Game Center.  The next Angry Birds update usually fixes achievements for people so hopefully PvZ gets an update.

Answer (score 2):

As Matthew says in the comment, there are sometimes bugs either with games or the Game Center. (I posted a similar question about missing achievements in Cut the Rope.) Unfortunately there is probably not anything you can do about this besides reporting the issue, which you can do via PvZ's entry in the App Store.

The only other thing I can suggest is double-check that you do indeed have everything - there should be 49 plants in all, including the Imitator. And try playing one level using the Imitator, just to make sure it's registered. (The same might go with other plants, if there is one you never planted during the course of the game.)